# keith-wood date picker dateFormat and language

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-format

I'm using the [Keith-Wood date picker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) and i´ve a problem with dateFormat.

When i use the following script everthing works fine:

```
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"});
```

(when a select a date the result is, for example, 2012-09-06)

but when i include the language setting the dateFormat is ignored

```
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick($.extend({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"}, $.datepick.regional['pt-BR']));
```

In this case, when a select a date the result is, for example, 09/06/2012 (corresponding to the default dateFormat mm/dd/yyyy).

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed if the mm/dd/yyyy format is not being introduced by the pt-BR localisation (as opposed to it reverting to the 'default' of the system).  That is, are you sure that the date format for pt-BR is not supposed to be mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Regardless of the language we should can set the our dateFormat. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution (not sure if it's the best one) but...

```
$.datepick.setDefaults($.datepick.regional['pt-BR']);   
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"});
```